# How to increase height of particular subview of stack view at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, view, stack

I have added some arrangedSubViews to vertical UIStackView.
and I want to increase height of one arranged subview inside on tap of some button.

Tried adding layoutIfNeeded on subview and main view.
Its Not working.

I am increasing height of subview as below :

```
addConstraints([self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)])
layoutIfNeeded()
sizeToFit()
layoutSubviews()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to add a new constraint to the view but **you didn't deactivate the existing constraint for heightAnchor**.

You could either set the isActive property of the existing height constraint to false before adding a new constraint or simply **set the constant of the existing height constraint to a new value.**

You can **give the constraint an identifier** which you can use later to get that specific constraint and change its property.

If I were you, I would add the following two extensions to my code:

```
extension UIView {
    func getConstraint(withIndentifier indentifier: String) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return self.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == indentifier }.first
    }
}

extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func activate(withIdentifier identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
// When you create the constraint:
subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).activate(withIdentifier: "THE")

// When you want to change the constant:
if let filteredConstraint = subview.getConstraint(withIndentifier: "THE") {
    filteredConstraint.constant = 500
}
```

If you want animation, just add the following code right after you changed the constraints:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I believe this will work, otherwise please let me know.

### Update

When you set the constraint like this:

```
self.myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).activate(withIdentifier: "topAnchor")
```

The constraint actually belongs to neither `myStackView` nor `someView`, but their superview. Although [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117352/10249377) is correct, personally I prefer [Kh_khan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57117191/10249377) in the comment:

```
self.myStackView.superView?.getConstraint(withIndentifier: "topAnchor")
```

Let me know whether it works.

Comment: that worked @Exquistian.
If I want to increase height with animation. Do u know how would I do it?

Comment: I just edited the answer and included how to animate the change as well.

Comment: height constraint works fine.
I have one topAnchor constraint which I want to change at run time:
  self.myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).activate(withIdentifier: "topAnchor")

But when I try to get its reference: if let filteredConstraint = self.myStackViewgetConstraint(withIndentifier: "topAnchor") {} 
Its not going into the block

Comment: @Exquisitian I'd like to reprint your `activate(withIdentifier:)` idea in my book. Is it original with you? If so, is that okay?

Comment: It is original and I've used it many times in my projects. It is ok as long as you mention it is created by the user Exquisitian on StackOverflow.com somewhere in the book. @matt

Comment: Will do, I’ll use the username and link to this answer. Thanks!