# Get NSLayoutConstraint Identifier is not working for topAnchor

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I want to change TopAnchor Constraint of some View at runtime .

Constraint Created:

```
 self.buttonHStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellHStack.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).activate(withIdentifier: "topAnchor")
```

### Extension

```
extension UIView {
    func getConstraint(withIndentifier indentifier: String) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return self.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == indentifier }.first
    }
}

extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func activate(withIdentifier identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.isActive = true
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
self.myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).activate(withIdentifier: "topAnchor")
```

But when I try to get its reference:

```
    if let filteredConstraint = self.myStackView.getConstraint(withIndentifier: "topAnchor") {

//Edit here
    }
```

Its not going into the block

Comment: A constraint between 2 views , is added to the parent of both
You need `self.myStackView.superView?.getConstraint(withIndentifier: "topAnchor")`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `getConstraint` on the wrong view. When you activate a constraint between `myStackView` and some other view:

```
self.myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: someView.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).activate(withIdentifier: "topAnchor")
```

...that constraint belongs to the common *superview* of `myStackView` and `someView`. So when you say

```
self.myStackView.getConstraint(withIndentifier: "topAnchor")
```

... it isn't there. You're looking in the wrong view for your constraint.

But your `getConstraint` method (evidently taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57102973/341994)) is a good idea, so let's rewrite it more correctly (and more elegantly) so that we walk up the view hierarchy looking for the constraint:

```
extension UIView {
    func constraint(withIdentifier id: String) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return self.constraints.first { $0.identifier == id } ??
               self.superview?.constraint(withIdentifier: id)
    }
}
```

Now (changing the name of course) your method call will work even when you call it on `myStackView`.